# asp core 2 angular spa routes don't work on refresh when making call to database

Tags: .net, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am having problems getting angular routes to work on page refresh in asp.net core 2 angular SPA.

It works fine if from test controller which creates some fake data, but when making call to the database returns..

NodeInvocationException: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'testroute',
    templateUrl: './testroute.component.html'
})
export class TestRouteComponent {
public jobs: TestJob[];

constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) 
{
    http.get(baseUrl + 'api/TestData/TestJobs').subscribe(result => {

        this.jobs = result.json() as TestJob[];
    }, error => console.log(error));
   }
 }
interface TestJob {
jobTitle: string;
}
```

testDataController (Works in app and on refresh)

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<TestJob> TestJobs()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        var jobs =  Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(index => new TestJob
        {
            JobTitle = JobTitles[rng.Next(JobTitles.Length)]
        });

        return jobs;
        }
    }

    public class TestJob
    {
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    }
```

savedjobscontroller method (Works when called from app but not on refresh)

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult SavedJobs()
    {
        try
        {
            var username = User.Identity.Name;

            var jobs = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Job>,
                IEnumerable<JobViewModel>>(
                userSavedJobsRepository.GetUserSavedJobs(username));

            return Ok(jobs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError($"Failed to get User Saved Jobs {ex}");
            return BadRequest("Failed to get User Saved Jobs");
        }
    }
```

If i call the method in the savejobs controller instead of the test controller, the route works as long as i redirect to it from within the app.  If I just put the url in the browser I'm getting the unexpected json at position 0 error.

I've tried everything i can find on here, changing routes in startup.cs etc.

The repsonse from both calls is in the same format so I don't see why the database / repository call is affecting it.

Works perfectly when creating the data in the test controller.

If anybody can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the JSON that's being returned when you get "Unexpected token?"

Comment: It's returning standard 500 internal server error, so it's not actually json.  If navigating from within the app, the json is the list of jobs as expected.  Seems really strange to me that the test method works when making call to controller but not when controller is calling db

Comment: If you debug your .Net Core code, what is the exception that results in an HTTP 500 internal server error?

Comment: That's part of my issue.  Not sure where to put breakpoints as it seems to be returning error as soon as it hits home index controller which is literally just public IActionResult(){ return View();}

Comment: I see. Why are you returning a View when you should be sending JSON to an Angular controller?

Comment: I'm not trying to, ha.  That's just how the the entry point for the spa is set up when you start a new .net angular project

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else is facing a similar issue, the only way I have found to get it working was to add the { useHash: true } in the routes.

Eg.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })

export class AppModule { }
```

Unfortunately, as the name suggests it adds /#/page to all of the urls, but pages do refresh and can navigate directly to pages by adding url in the browser.